# How to Get Css File Dynamically In My Html Page

Tags: html, css, ajax

I have multiple html pages with the same navbar. I recently put the navbar in it's own navbar.html file and use ajax via jquery.get() to dynamically load the navbar onto my pages, as opposed to repeating the code across all my pages.

There is currently no stylesheet on the navbar.html, as the style gets applied when the navbar gets loaded back onto the calling page.

Should I be including the .css in the navbar.html, also? They would both be referencing the same 2 stylesheets. I assume that's possible, but haven't yet tested - it will definitely make it easier to make changes to this file in the future.  What's the best practice here? I will not be using any server side code.

Please also let me know if there is a more conventional way to do this; I haven't had any luck searching.  (I come from a .net web forms background, so would just use a master page there.)

Any relevant links would also be appreciated.

Comment: using angular.js looks better to me. You won't need to load the html separately. You can use directives for navbar, header, footer etc. Only the main content will change based on routes.

Comment: @NikhileshKV it's the same idea.

Comment: That's not going to be a good practice, in terms of rendering. 

Try using some templating language, like 'jade', 'mustache', 'handlebars'... in order to keep just 1 template of your navbar.

Trust me, you'll have to invest a bit of time to start with, but you're gonna get much better workflow for the future.

Anyway, if you still wanna load your navbar with ajax, you don't need to include all the styles, you can use the same as you're main page is using. Just put the tags you want to inject in your page.

Answer (score -1):

Check the snippet

```html
First you have to  make you pages index.php
Then include your navbar.php to index.php using <?php include'navbar.php';?>

Use below method to active the button on each pages

1- Define your page name <?php $page = 'company';?>
2- Define a active class in css file
3- Call the active class to button
   

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```